# jQuery/PHP file upload restarts at 99% and then returns timeout

Tags: php, jquery, apache, upload, timeout

I'm having some issues with jQuery/PHP file uploading on my AMI Linux running on EC2 instance.
I tried using [this](https://github.com/danielm/uploader) and a couple other plugins (just to ensure the problem wasnt with the plugin itself), with the same results.
When trying to upload a 14MB PDF the progress bar reaches 75% (or more, up to 99%), then it restarts from 0%, it reaches again 75% (or more, up to 99%) and then it just stops with no error (not even saying `Request Timeout`).
Doing several attempts, only a couple of times the progress bar reached 99% without restarting, and then error popped up saying `Request Timeout`.
This is what i found in apache's `access_log`:

> 12.34.56.78 - - [02/Jul/2019:15:50:09 +0000] "POST /uploader/demo/backend/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 408 221
>
> 12.34.56.78 - - [02/Jul/2019:15:50:31 +0000] "POST /uploader/demo/backend/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 408 221

So it prints `408 Request Timeout` on 2 lines (infact the upload restarts once). The upload takes 22 or 23 seconds (as can be seen in the logs).

This is how i set my `php.ini` (i'm using PHP 7.1 FPM):

```
max_execution_time = 360
max_input_time = 360
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

`phpinfo()` shows that those values are properly applied.
I also tried to use `set_time_limit(0)` and set all above values in the `upload.php` file with `ini_set()`, but nothing changed.
Upload directory has proper permissions, infact an 9.3MB PDF is uploaded correctly with no errors.

In one of my attempts i tried also to set these apache directives:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 360
TimeOut 360
```

With the only result that the upload progress kept reaching 99% and restarting several times instead than restating only once.

Now i run out of ideas and most solutions proposed are related to `php.ini` settings which in my case are properly applied.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of attempts, as soon as i posted my question, i found the answer. It might be useful to anyone having the same issue. If everything else listed in my question doesnt work, it might be due to [mod_reqtimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) (as it was for me).
I simply created a file named: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_reqtimeout.conf`
and put this inside of it:

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>
```

as suggested by the apache doc linked above. Then i restarted apache and the upload reached 100% with no problems.

Also `mod_security` has taken part in this when i tried with a 60MB PDF. I had to set the following setting to match the 100MB limit that was set in `php.ini`, inside `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf`:

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 100000000
```